# Ionic serve not working with ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have started a clean project with ionic2 based on tabs template, by following the next steps:

```
$ ionic start <myapp> --v2
$ cd <myapp>
$ ionic serve
```

Then the output from `ionic serve` is just:

```
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /home/luan/<myapp>
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
```

If I try to open `localhost:8100` there's no response.

The files and code of the project are just the same as one using tabs template, but it's just don't wonking.
Could someone help?

UPDATE:
My `ionic info`

```
My system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.2
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer. It turns out, the `1.2.2` version of Ionic App Scripts (app-scripts) version was the problem. Just downgraded to `1.1.4` and works fine. The actual workaround:

in `package.json`, change

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.2.2"
```

to

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4"
```

then run `npm install` again. It should show something like this:

```
[...]
- sentence-case@2.1.1 node_modules/sentence-case
- change-case@3.0.1 node_modules/change-case
ionic-hello-world@ /home/luan/Projetos/prestacontas
└── @ionic/app-scripts@1.1.4 ## The problem was here
```

Make shure that @ionic/app-scripts is now 1.1.4, and not 1.2.2.

And that's it.

Comment: This worked for me. Is this the latest version of app-scripts that can work?

Comment: @daraul The 1.2.2 version will only work on the ionic@beta version (this will be ionic3), but it's not recommended to update now, specially if your app is already in development or production. You can check that [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2045) and [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2046). The best to do is keep the "last stable" version (1.1.4) if using ionic2.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried using

npm run ionic:serve

Comment: I just had this issue today with a later version of the app-scripts 1.3.7 and this answer worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for you,,, :)

Most probably this can be an issue of updating. Because I opened two of my ionic projects. one is from late 2017. For that project live reload is working without an issue. The problem with my new project. I checked the "ionic info" and found that both are same other than the ionic framework version. my older one is v 3.7.1. unfortunately, that version not installing now. don't know exactly what the problem is.
However, I found a solution,

instead of "Ionic serve" command run the following command for the first time. then you will not need to run "ionic serve" each time.

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I updated Ionic. I worked around it by using:

```
ionic serve --address localhost
```

The above solution to use "@ionic/app-script": "1.2.2" works to have it use localhost instead of 0.0.0.0. However it created other errors that were easily fixed by following the addition warnings.

> "devDependencies": {
>       "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.2.2",

The one new error I still couldn't pinpoint yet is:

> Error Close Runtime Error timeStamp.getDate is not a function Stack
>   TypeError: timeStamp.getDate is not a function
>       at HomePage.timeSince (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:70141:33)
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:70088:42)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69844:16)
>       at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69793:22)
>       at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69746:26)
>       at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69710:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44518:38)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27788:37)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13987) Ionic Framework: 2.0.0-rc.2 Ionic Native: 2.2.3 Ionic App Scripts:
>   1.2.2 Angular Core: 2.1.1 Angular Compiler CLI: 2.1.1 Node: 6.9.1 OS Platform: Windows 10 Navigator Platform: Win32 User Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36

The app does run but that window popped up on Chrome and I had to close it before I could see the output of the app.

Comment: I have also tried that the first time (using localhost), and it have not worked. the best solution is yet to change the version of ionic scripts. About the new error that is probably just an import or dependence missing. Try running a `git grep getDate` to identify where the function is being called and fix the import. Although, it may not work, sorry... rs